# ViewBinding - do we need to remove clicklisteners to avoid memory leaks?

Tags: android, memory-leaks, android-viewbinding

When using Android [ViewBinding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding) do you then have to explicitly remove clickListeners to avoid memory leaks or is that all handlede with releasing the binding?

```
binding.button.setOnClickListener { }

override fun onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView()
    binding = null
}
```

Comment: Are you storing a copy of `binding` inside your `OnClickListener` instance? Otherwise I'm not sure what leak you're worried about. Could you elaborate with a concrete example where you think a leak could occur?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Memory leak appears only if you adding `Fragment` instance to the backstack without clearing that `Fragment` view fields in `Fragment.onDestroyView()` callback.

Yes you should do it manually, `ViewBinding` do not have desired implementation.
If you do not want to do it manually you can write your own delegate that do it automatically or use well designed [library](https://github.com/kirich1409/ViewBindingPropertyDelegate).

Comment: The libary you are linking to seems to do nothing more about clicklisteners than `binding = null` - which you stated does not solve the problem?

Comment: If your listeners do not using or store objects which lifecycle greater than view fragment lifecycle there should not be any problem with them.